# How to put users in a queue base on their login time?

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, queue

I want to put my logged in users in a queue based on their login time , so that the site could handle their requests one by one. But I don't know the proper solution for this problem.
And one more thing ! my programming language is Asp .Net MVC ,but PHP ,Asp .net Core are accepted too .
Thanx

Comment: How can we help with any knowledge about your users... How are they logged in, do you log the time when the sign in, etc

Comment: @Vince Yes,I log the time when my users log in,and also the time that they log out ,so I have the log in/out time

Comment: It is useful to have more information. Are you using a database? What happens if a user disconnects without logging off? The last login time could be days ago, so you might not want to include those. If you have a table or list you can use LINQ to sort them in date order

Comment: @pixelda        Yes I'm using asp .net Identity system ,so I have a database.The more accurate description for the project is that we have a session in which we can answer our clients in a row;like a agency that answer its clients in a room one by one ,I make the backend to check if the user is available in the session or not ,I.e every one minutes.I am using big blue button for my sessions . i need an interface to put my users in a queue to log them in to the session one by one

Comment: You can add a table into identity that stores a user ID and login time - either last login time or every login time, depending if you need that data. In the identity controller just add your record to your table once a successful login occurs. Another option is to consider SignalR as this can communicate both ways. In this case, log when a user goes to the request page rather than when they log in.